# Jquery not working in Webbrowser control when page is loaded from another jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, webbrowser-control

This issue is very specific so I'm not sure if anyone has encountered it before but I'm posting this question in case anyone has ideas...

I have a vb.net application with a Webbrowser control. The app creates html pages which includes jquery code and loads them into the Webbrowser control using the `.navigate`

Here's a simplified example of what's happening:

1. I create a page with a DIV. That DIV has mouseover and onclick events bound
   using jquery.
2. When the user clicks that DIV, it calls a vb.net
   function like this `'onclick = window.external.MyFunction()'`
3. This calls my .net function `MyFunction` which creates a new html page (which also includes jquery code)
4. When that page loads into the same Webbrowser control the jquery events on it (*click, mouseover, etc*) don't work.

Some example code:

This Jquery code works on the first page, but not the next page

```
onmouseover="$('#my_div').css('visibility','visible');"
```

This Javascript code works on the first page and the next page

```
onmouseover="document.getElementById('my_div').style.visibility = 'visible';"
```

Caveats:

- I verified JQuery is running correctly. I'm using jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js
- I'm testing my app using different versions of installed IE. It works fine in 7, 8, and 11. I get this issue if 9 and 10 are installed.
- If I open the generated webpage in an IE browser, it works fine
- If I hit 'F5' in my app to refresh the webbrowser control once the next page is loaded, it works fine
- If I use javascript events instead of Jquery, it works. I'd prefer not to do this because I use Jquery all throughout my application.
- **Hack to make it work:** If I change my vb.net `MyFunction` to trigger a Timer and that timer event calls the '*build next page*' logic, it works fine. Although this works, I can't really use it and would prefer to figure out and fix the underlying problem. The fact that this works leads me to believe there's some solution here...just not sure what it is.

Comment: I had similar problems some time ago. jQuery UI didn't really load the new page contents like the browser would. It just retrieved the page's content and displays it, no JavaScript evaluation at all. Did you check the console output on the error-versions?

Comment: There are no javascript errors. The page works fine if I load it into a browser. It also works if I F5 refresh the webbrowser control. Because the timer hack works, it leads me to believe there's something quirky happening with the order of events. Doesn't Work: click event triggers vb function which loads another page into the same browser control that triggered the original click event. Works: click event triggers vb function which triggers timer. Timer calls function that loads another page into the same browser control that triggered the original click event

Comment: Did you try disabling the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` of the WebBrowser and checking the error (there has to be some error)? If this doesn't work could you try to check [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)? There's a lite-version available if you paste this code into your HTML `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>` . Check if `$` is defined and whether anything related to jQuery works.

Comment: There are no js errors. As I said above, if I use pure javascript, it works fine. Something is happening with the jquery. And yes `$ ` is initialized. The `$(document).ready(function() {` function fires correctly. Also keep in mind it's only not working on computers with IE9 and 10. When I test with systems which have IE7, 8, and 11, it works fine. There's nothing different about the systems either...I took an IE9 computer that didn't work, upgraded to IE11 and now it works. I think I'm going to have to go with my _Timer Hack_ until I figure out something better.

Comment: I understood your problem, I just thought that there might be suppressed warnings/errors or that `$` wasn't initialized. I took a short look at the [development jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js) and didn't see anything related to your problem yet. You should [file an issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues), this really seems to be a bug in jQuery. And I reccommend trying out a .NET WebKit-control, because if you're shipping out a single version of the browser component you're safe from different version problems. If you don't want that, go with your solutions.

Comment: Yea, I do plan on looking into the Webkit control at some point, right now my entire application is specific to the IE webbrowser control so switching is a big task. My hack is working for now so I'll live with it. Thanks for all your suggestions on this.